# I'm trying to send multiple files over socket, and the server is getting stuck after a file transfer

Tags: python, file, sockets, binary, transfer

Why, I have no idea, but the server is getting stuck on `bytes_read = connection.recv(BUFFER)` after the file transfer.

So you know BUFFER is 4096.

client.py

```py
                with open(filename, "rb") as file:
                    while True:
                        bytes_read = file.read(BUFFER)
                        if bytes_read == b'':
                            client.send(b'<EOF>')
                            break

                        client.sendall(bytes_read)
                        progress.update(len(bytes_read))
                progress.close()
                client.recv(BUFFER).decode()
```

server.py

```py
                with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
                    while True:
                        bytes_read = connection.recv(BUFFER)
                        if bytes_read == b'<EOF>':
                            break
                            
                        file.write(bytes_read)
                        progress.update(len(bytes_read))
                    progress.close()
                    connection.send('release'.encode())
```

When I walk through the code everything works fine, but when I run the code the server gets stuck on `bytes_read = connection.recv(BUFFER)` and never sees the `bytes_read == b'<EOF>'`.

Could it be that the packet being sent is to small?

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol. You can't expect to receive exactly what is sent in a single `send`. You can't rely on a single  `b'<EOF>'` received so the server will hang.

Comment: Your client is never closing the socket, so the server will never see end of stream.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that checking the file size in a while loop will work.

client.py

```py
                with open(filename, "rb") as file: 
                     while True: 
                         _bytes = file.read(BUFFER) 
                         if _bytes == b'': 
                             progress.update(len(_bytes)) 
                             break 
  
                         client.sendall(_bytes) 
                         progress.update(len(_bytes)) 
                 client.recv(BUFFER).decode()
```

server.py

```py
                file_data = b'' 
                 with open(filename, 'wb') as file: 
                     while len(file_data) < filesize: 
                         _bytes = connection.recv(BUFFER) 
                         file_data += _bytes 
                         file.write(file_data) 
                         progress.update(len(_bytes))
```

Comment: No it won't. This might work if all files are multiples of the buffer size, but not otherwise. If you know the file size in advance you should read exactly that many bytes from the stream, counting them carefully, and making sure to handle the last buffer correctly, as it usually will have to be smaller buffer, unless again the file size happens to be a multiple of the buffer size. At present your code will most likely over-run the correct file size.

Comment: But it hasn't. It works just fine. This is only part of the code. It goes in sequence. The folder first, filename second, then the file size. After that it starts transferring the data. This repeats until all the data has been transfered. The whole point of this is to send everything from the source computer to the recycle bin instead of deleting  it.